# How do I get the max records of a max subset in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following tables:

Training Occurrence

```
Id   Training Id   Due Date
5    1             09/01/2018
6    1             09/15/2018
7    2             09/01/2018
```

Training Occurrence User

```
Id   Training Material Occurrence Id   User Id
1    5                                 'Chad'
2    5                                 'Chad'
3    6                                 'Chad'
4    6                                 'Chad'
5    7                                 'Chad'
```

My query needs to get the newest Training Material Occurrence User record of the newest Training Material Occurrence table. So if I pass in the user 'Chad'

I would want to see:

```
Id   Occurrence Id   User     Training Id   Due Date
4    6               'Chad'   1             09/15/2018
5    7               'Chad'   2             09/01/2018
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT tmou.*, tmo.TrainingMaterialId, tmo.DueDate
FROM dbo.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceUser as tmou
INNER JOIN dbo.TrainingMaterialOccurrence as tmo on
tmou.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceId = tmo.Id
AND tmou.Id IN (SELECT MAX(tmou.Id)
        FROM dbo.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceUser as tmou
        WHERE tmou.UserId = @UserId
        AND tmou.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceId IN (SELECT MAX(tmo.Id) as occurrenceId
                              FROM dbo.TrainingMaterialOccurrence as tmo
                               WHERE tmo.Id IN (Select TrainingMaterialOccurrenceId FROM dbo.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceUser as tmou1 WHERE tmou1.UserId = @UserId)
                            GROUP BY tmo.TrainingMaterialId)
        GROUP BY tmou.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceId)
```

As you can see this is a mess. Any ideas on how I can clean this up.

Comment: I don't understand your expected results.  Why 5-7-chad doesn't have training ID and due date?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I had a typo there. I fixed it. The second row should have had training ID and due date.

Comment: Please tag your request with the DBMS. I suppose it's SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Rank your rows with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT Id, TrainingMaterialOccurrenceId, UserId, TrainingMaterialId, DueDate
FROM
(
  SELECT
    tmou.Id,
    tmou.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceId,
    tmou.UserId,
    tmo.TrainingMaterialId,
    tmo.DueDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tmo.TrainingMaterialId
                      ORDER BY tmo.DueDate DESC,
                               tmo.Id DESC,
                               tmou.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceId DESC,
                               tmou.Id DESC) AS rn
  FROM dbo.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceUser as tmou
  INNER JOIN dbo.TrainingMaterialOccurrence as tmo
          ON tmo.Id = tmou.TrainingMaterialOccurrenceId
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```